# I want to duplicate image using a for loop in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, for-loop, duplicates

I currently have no idea how to solve this problem. But I want to be able to duplicate the image based on the number sent to my method. here's what I have

```
dynamic _printImage(icon) { 
return Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    for (var i = 0; i < icon; i++) {
      Image.asset(
        "assets/coin.svg",
      );
    }
  ],
); }
```

This is the error code I'm currently getting

[image: Error Returned]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add [`flutter_svg: version`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) in pubspec.yaml and then

```
dependencies:
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.1
```

you can try :

```
  dynamic _printImage(icon) {
    return Row(
      children: List.generate(
        icon,
        (index) =>  SvgPicture.asset(
          "assets/coin.svg",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

or :

```
  dynamic _printImage(icon) {
    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      for (var i = 0; i < icon; i++)
         SvgPicture.asset(
          "assets/coin.svg",
        )
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but these doesn't work. It reuturns    _Exception (Exception: Invalid image data)

Comment: It must works. What is error?   https://pasteboard.co/r1G0fVdislVv.png  @Foozaweb

Comment: _Exception (Exception: Invalid image data).  I tried this before. But lemme try SvgPicture as suggested by @Juan Carlos Ramón Condezo. Thanks.

Comment: look `assets/coin.svg` is present? How do you declear your images in pubspec.yaml?@Foozaweb

Comment: Thank you. it worked. Though I has to use PNG because I couldn't get the dependency. pub.dev server is not reachable. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `dynamic` when possible.

The method provided by Cyrus is just fine, but Image Widget does not support SVG images.
So, You can use: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

```dart
Widget _printImage(icon) {
    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      for (var i = 0; i < icon; i++)
        SvgPicture.asset(
          "assets/coin.svg",
        )
    ],
  );
}
```